# Setting up my WPF solution and the "Project doesn't know how to run the profile" error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I've created a solution in VS2022 using the WPF application template (not the one that says (.net framework)) and when trying to run it I get the error popping up:
"The project doesn't know how to run the profile with name 'wpftestproject' and comment 'Project'."
See the image below, it's not an output window error but an actual pop-up window.

[image]

I'm on Windows 10 pro and trying to get this template solution to run (it should pop up a MainWindow).

I have no idea what could be the source of this issue and I'm not finding anything online.
One thing I noticed is that under application properties the "Target framework" is default to .NET6.0 and not .NET CORE 3.0 for some reason. Though changing this isn't fixing it.

I've also tried having a look over my VS installation, it doesn't seem to me that anything is missing but maybe someone else knows something:

[image]

Comment: You can also try updating your vs to the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you need to install correctly, `.Net desktop development` and `universal windows platform development`.(Try to reinstall `.Net desktop development`)

[image]

And install the packages you need in individual components.

[image]

If reinstalling these does not help you, I suggest you choose update->repair

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the second option of update->repair worked for me.